# A better way to return '1' if a left join returns any rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have three tables, 'A', 'B' and 'C'.  I have query on 'A' and 'B', but I want to add a field that tells me whether or not there is one or more (I dont' care how many) 'C' that are foreign keyed to 'A'.

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT    A.A_id, A.col_2, col_3, B.col_2, A.col_4
          count(C.id) as C_count
FROM      A
JOIN      B ON (A.B_id = B.B_id)
LEFT JOIN C ON (A.A_id = C.A_id)
WHERE     A.A_id = ?
GROUP BY  A.A_id, A.col_2, col_3, B.col_2, A.col_4
ORDER BY  CASE WHEN A.col_2 = ?
               THEN 0
               ELSE 1 
          END, col_3;
```

It seems a little inefficient, both because I have to list all those fields in the `GROUP BY` and also because I'm counting where all I really want is whether there is at least one match or not.  Can this be improved?

Comment: Just because you had to type a lot of column names doesn't make a query inefficient ;)  In this case though, you're correct. Sorting and tabulating the count is costly, but perhaps even more costly is that the DB has to go through ALL of the rows in Table C to get that count. With the EXISTS solution as soon as it finds the first matching row it can stop looking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use Exists with a subquery instead...

```
 Select A.A_id, A.col_2, col_3, 
    B.col_2, A.col_4, 
    Case When Exists (Select * From C
                      Where A_id = A.A_id)
         Then 1 Else 0 End As C_Exists
 From A Join B 
     On (A.B_id = B.B_id) 
 Where A.A_id = ?    
 Order By Case When A.col_2 = ? 
           Then 0 Else 1 End, col_3;
```

Comment: Excellent.  EXPLAIN PLAN says it's better, too.  3 minutes until I can accept it.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: That's because EXISTS will return true as soon as the first successful match to the criteria is found - there's no need for EXISTS to check of all matching criteria.